# How to use img src from vuex by looping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to call the image source from vuex by looping it in div 
I mean like this.

```
<div v-for="({image}, index) in allData" :key="index">
  <img src="this.image" alt="this.index"/>
</div>

<script>
  import {mapState} from 'vuex';
  export default{
    computed: {
      ...mapState([
        'allData'
      ])
    }
  }
</script>
```

this is data.js

```
export default [
  {image: "./image/image1"},
  {image: "./image/image2"},
  {image: "./image/image3"}
]
```

this is state.js

```
import data from './data'
export default {data};
```

this is index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import state from './state'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({state})
```

[image]

thank you

Comment: please share the relevant parts of vuex store code

Comment: I think you want `:src="image"` and `:alt="index"`. Put a `:` out front and get rid of the `this`.

Comment: hello skirtle, i tried it, but it still doesn't work, but it's not error, it just show the alt text with no picture

Comment: Inspect the element in the developer tools to see what value the `src` ends up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the double quotes when binding the attribute. Remember that for local images you need to places them into the folder `public/assets`, then you can change your URLs to `assets/your-image-name.jpg`. More informations about static assets in Vue.JS can be found [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation).

```
<template>
   <div v-for="({ image }, index) in allData" :key="index">
      <img 
         :src="image" 
         :alt="index"
      />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
   computed: {
      ...mapState(['allData'])
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you federico-dondi, i will try to follow the link

Comment: Thank you federico-dondi, it solved, my problem was in data.js, and i must use a bind

Comment: Happy to be helpful.